# Placing some tick labels on the right in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

Consider the following plot.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        width=5cm,
        height=7cm,
        domain=-90:90,
        xtick={-90, 0, 90},
        ytick={-1, .6, 1, -.2},
      ]
    \addplot {sin(x)};
    \addplot {.2 - .4*sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Say I want to have the tick labels for the y coordinates `-1` and `0.6` on the left, but the ones for `-0.2` and `1` on the right. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add a second axis with `axis y line*=right` and add the y ticks to that one. As long as `ymin` and `ymax` for both axes coincide that works.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a conditional style. Here I reordered the ticks and use the axis `width` to specify the `xshift`.

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
            scale only axis,
            width=5cm,
            height=7cm,
            domain=-90:90,
            xtick={-90, 0, 90},
            ytick={-1,-0.2,0.6,1},
            every y tick label/.append style={
                xshift={isodd(\ticknum) ? \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width} : "0pt"},
                anchor={isodd(\ticknum) ? 180 : 0}
            },
        ]
        \addplot {sin(x)};
        \addplot {.2 - .4*sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]